# Yii2 default sorting is not working

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I need to do default sorting by id, we don't show id in grid that's why default sorting is not working here is my code for sorting

```
public function search($params)
    {   
        $this->load($params);
        $query = new \yii\db\Query;
        $expression = new \yii\db\Expression('CASE WHEN b.status = 1 THEN "Active" WHEN  b.status = 2 THEN "Inactive" END AS status');
        $query->select(['b.image','bl.name',$expression,'b.brand_id'])  
              ->from('brand AS b')
              ->join('INNER JOIN', 
                    'brand_lang AS bl',
                    'bl.brand_id = b.brand_id AND lang_id = 1'); 

        $query->andFilterWhere([            
            'status' => $this->status,
        ]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name]);

        $command = $query->createCommand();
        $data = $command->queryAll();       
        $dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'totalCount' => count($data),
            'sort' => [
                'attributes' => [
                    'name' => [
                        'asc' => ['name' => SORT_ASC, 'name' => SORT_ASC],
                        'desc' => ['name' => SORT_DESC, 'name' => SORT_DESC],
                        'default' => SORT_DESC,
                        'label' => 'Name',
                    ],
                    'status' => [
                        'asc' => ['status' => SORT_ASC, 'status' => SORT_ASC],
                        'desc' => ['status' => SORT_DESC, 'status' => SORT_DESC],
                        'default' => SORT_DESC,
                        'label' => 'Status',
                    ],
                    'brand_id' => [
                        'asc' => ['brand_id' => SORT_ASC, 'brand_id' => SORT_ASC],
                        'desc' => ['brand_id' => SORT_DESC, 'brand_id' => SORT_DESC],
                        'default' => SORT_ASC,
                        'label' => 'Brand',
                    ],
                    'defaultOrder' => ['brand_id' => SORT_ASC]
                ],
            ],
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 20,
            ],
        ]); 
        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

Can anyone please tell me what is solution for this ? I did lots of googling but didn't success

Answer (score 1):

Your [`defaultOrder`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sort.html#$defaultOrder-detail) param should be in [`sort`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-basedataprovider.html#$sort-detail), not in [`attributes`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sort.html#$attributes-detail) :

```
'sort' => [
    'attributes' => [...],
    'defaultOrder' => ['brand_id' => SORT_ASC],
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$dataProvider->sort->attributes['attribute_name']`:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,

        'sort' => [ 
            'defaultOrder' => ['brand_id' => SORT_ASC] 
        ],
    ]);

    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['name'] = [
        'asc' => ['name' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['name' => SORT_DESC],
    ];
```

Comment: You answer is correct, but what is standard, why it is not being use inside sort array.

Comment: @HiteshJangid. [defaultOrder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sort.html#$defaultOrder-detail)